# Autocomplete show and save 2 different map details on same page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to setup a page that has 2 different addresses and displays with maps using the google maps api from autocomplete. I have one working great but I cannot get 2 working on different divs? I would also like to post the data from both as variables as working on the first.

The html I have working for one but not the other is :

```
<div id="pickup-details">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
<input id="searchInput" onfocus="this.value=''" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter pickup address">
<div id="map"></div>
</div>

<div id="dropoff-details">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12">
    <input id="searchInput2" onfocus="this.value=''" class="controls2" type="text" placeholder="Enter dropoff address">
    <div id="map2"></div>
    </div>
```

The css is :

```
#map {width: 100%;height: 300px;}

.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#searchInput {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 50%;
}
#searchInput:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#map2 {width: 100%;height: 300px;}

.controls2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#searchInput2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 50%;
}
#searchInput2:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}
```

and the js I have is :

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 52.48757519999999, lng: -1.9116437000000133},
      zoom: 13
  });

  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
      center: {lat: 52.48757519999999, lng: -1.9116437000000133},
      zoom: 13
  });


    var input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
        }
        marker.setIcon(({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);




        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[3] && place.address_components[3].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[4] && place.address_components[4].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[5] && place.address_components[5].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

      //clear all//
      document.getElementById('postal_code').value=null;
      document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value=null;
      document.getElementById('locality').value=null;
      document.getElementById('route').value=null;
      document.getElementById('street_number').value=null;
      document.getElementById('place_name').value=null;
        //Location details

                for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'postal_code'){
                document.getElementById('postal_code').value=place.address_components[i].short_name;
            }
            if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'country'){
                document.getElementById('administrative_area_level_1').value=place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }
             if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'locality'){

                document.getElementById('locality').value=place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }
             if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'route'){
                 var test2 = value=place.address_components[i].long_name;
                document.getElementById('route').value=place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }
             if(place.address_components[i].types[0] == 'street_number'){
                 var test1 = value=place.address_components[i].long_name;
                document.getElementById('street_number').value=place.address_components[i].long_name;
            }

            test3 = test1+' '+test2;
            test4 = place.name; 
            if (test3 == test4) {
                document.getElementById('place_name').value=null; 
            }

            if (test3 != test4) {
                document.getElementById('place_name').value=place.name; 
            }

                }


                document.getElementById('show_pick_up').innerHTML = place.name+' '+place.formatted_address;
                      $('#show_pick_up').show();
                //document.getElementById('place_name').value=place.name; 
                //document.getElementById('route').value=place.address_components[1].short_name; 
                //document.getElementById('postal_code').value=place.address_components[6].short_name;
    });
}
```

Comment: There is only one map in the posted code. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: what exactly do you want me to show? I don't have anything as I cant get it to work, all I want is 2 separate maps that's get a location and display it. I can repost everything I have tried if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create and initialize your 2 maps separately. You should store references to your 2 maps. This example is taken straight from Google Maps API examples: [Simple Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) You will see 2 maps starting at 2 different locations.

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
  
  map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
    center: {lat: 42.2007934, lng: -85.604063},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
}
#map2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="map2"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks it sort of works, but I display each in different DIVS and unless I move the second one or resize screen it does not show? Also when look back at the first one t has half gone?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are saying or asking. The example I created shows each in different DIVS. They both display and you can locate them wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is sorted with the map not loading automatically, I just had to add the below when the div was reloaded

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));